# why only "main" work in require.js? define("main", ['jquery'], function ()

Tags: jquery, asp.net, requirejs

I had define the `require.js` for testing purpose

```
define("test", ['jquery'], function () {
    debugger;
    $('#button').bind('click', function () {
        alert("halo");
    });
});
```

If I use word "test", as I had a javascipt file "test.js", it is not working
but if I use word "main"

```
define("main", ['jquery'], function () {
    debugger;
    $('#button').bind('click', function () {
        alert("halo");
    });
});
```

It works great, either in ASP.NET form or external js file, I still can't get it. Any guide to refer what I am doing wrong?
I declare in path.config in main.js

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '../Scripts/lib/',
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'jquery-2.0.0',
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you clarify what works and what doesn't (and how?), what files are these bits of code saved under? *"It works great, (...), I still can't get it."* <- somewhat confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I still new to require.js, and yesterday I did a self test, and browse through different guideline, and figure out that the answer is define(TARGET js, [array of js]), thats the reason why my "main" work as jquery is inside the main.js, puzzle solved